# Finding out which button selected and posting it with mobile jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm not too familiar with jQuery/JS, and my Google foo has failed me.

I'm trying to find out which of the `li` are selected so that it can be posted to a new page. This is probably not very complex, and maybe I'm just looking in all the wrong places.

```
     <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Adgangskontrol
        </h3>
        <form action="">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Medarbejder
                </li>
                <li data-theme="">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                        DH
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                        MLP
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>  
            </div>

        </form>
        <input data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" value="Send oplysninger" type="submit" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems you may want radio buttons in each of your LI tags.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="myRadioGroup" value="radio one is checked" />
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="myRadioGroup" value="radio two is checked" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Then, server side, set up a case or if/else statement

```
if(myRadioGroup=="radio one is checked")
{
  // process firstName input
}
else if(myRadioGroup=="radio two is checked")
{
 // process lastName input
}
```

Maybe you only want the last INPUT the user filled out to be used server side. If so, you could use JavaScript to dynamically select the radio associated with the INPUT... but then you might be better off using a single hidden INPUT to store "radio one is checked"(or whatever).

Oh, one other thing is that you can have multiple FORMs on page, in each of your LIs, the only issue is that they would each have to have their own submit button.

Hopefully I've given you something to go on. There's many ways to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I'm afraid my wording might have been a little off, what im looking for is actually making the "li"s like a ratio button. So the sample form would post the selected button value and some input text fields if i wanted to later on.

Comment: Well, technically everything within the FORM tag will be sent to the server. What you might want to do is add radios to your form, read the radio value server side and then decide which form items you want to use based on that.

Comment: Your radio buttons (a radio group) will all have the same `name` attribute but you set a different value to each one... I'll change my answer and illustrate.